# Using the Symfony 2 Event Dispatcher

Tags: php, events, symfony

How, if at all, should a Symfony 2 bundle developer use the event dispatcher(s) that ship with a stock Symfony 2 system?

I've been digging around in the source for Symfony's event dispatcher, and some of what I've seen has me a little confused as to how I, a third party bundle creator, should use the event dispatcher that ships with Symfony.

Specifically, I noticed that a stock Symfony system has **two** event dispatcher services.  The `event_dispatcher` and the `debug.event_dispatcher`. Which service the **HttpKernel** uses is dependent on environment, and driven by the generated dev or prod container file.

```
//dev kernel instantiation uses `debug.event_dispatcher` service
new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel(
            $this->get('debug.event_dispatcher'), 
            $this, 
            $this->get('debug.controller_resolver')
        );

//prod kernel instantiation uses `event_dispatcher` service         
new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel(
            $this->get('event_dispatcher'), 
            $this, 
            new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver($this, $this->get('controller_name_converter'), $this->get('monolog.logger.request', ContainerInterface::NULL_ON_INVALID_REFERENCE)));
```

So far this all makes sense — as it's the `debug.event_dispatcher` that implements functionality in the web profile's event's tab, including the ability to see which listeners were called, and which listeners were not called.

However, I noticed most (if not all) third party bundles use a hard coded `event_dispatcher` service call.  For example, the [JMS/JobQueueBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSJobQueueBundle/blob/master/Command/RunCommand.php#L71) uses the following

```
$this->dispatcher = $this->getContainer()->get('event_dispatcher');
```

Events dispatched like this fire correctly, **but** the `debug.event_dispatcher` doesn't know about them, which means the Symfony web profiler will incorrectly list a called listener as uncalled.  Additionally, it's not clear how a bundle author could avoid this, as they don't have the advantage of generating a container file **and** the HTTP Kernel object doesn't expose an accessor for the protected dispatcher object.

So, is this a bug in Symfony?

Or is the `event_dispatcher` service only intended for Kernel events, meaning all those bundle authors are misusing it?

Or (the most likely candidate), is it something else I'm missing or haven't considered?

Comment: If you are creating your own bundle, you can use your own even dispatcher. The only reason to use the built in event_dispatcher service is to use kernel events which you don't always needs. But still then your question is valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the scenario I described above doesn't apply to that latest version of Symfony (`2.4.1`).  Specifically, in `2.4.1`, the generated app container file

```
app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php
```

contains the following

```
$this->aliases = array(
    //...
    'event_dispatcher' => 'debug.event_dispatcher',
    //...
);
```

That is, unlike the Symfony `2.3.6` project I was working on, the `event_dispatcher` service has been aliased to the `debug.event_dispatcher` service (when Symfony runs in development mode).  This means when other bundles ask for an `event_dispatcher` service in dev mode, they're really getting a `debug.event_dispatcher` service.  This lets the the `debug.event_dispatcher` know about all the events, and it can correctly report on which ones were dispatched.

While it's not a concrete answer, it does indicate the Symfony team was/is aware of the issue, which leads me to believe it's their intention for Bundle developers to use the `event_dispatch` service fro their own events.